# Is it possible to create post in wordpress using postman?

Tags: wordpress, api, authentication, postman, wordpress-rest-api

We have tried to create a post in wordpress using postman, cant able to create one since we have received error as you are not allowed to do this action

Eventhough i entered the admin login, it gives the same error !!!!

This is the exact error message ,

```
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_create",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

I have tried using this URL in the postman (post) method  **http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts**

And in the authorization entered the **admin credentials** of my application.

Any alternative solutions are also appreciable .....Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin available in WordPress for Basic Authentication configuration, that will help. It's free for Basic Authentication you can search the plugin name **REST API Authentication** in your site and configure the Basic Authentication setup. And you can create the post using the WordPress endpoints.
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/

Note : It will be safer to create a new user by having **Author** role. So that use can access the site only for creating the posts.
Here I'm adding the plugin documentation for reference
https://plugins.miniorange.com/wordpress-rest-api-basic-authentication-method

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code

```
$username = 'yourwordpress login username';
$password = 'your wordpress login password';
$rest_api_url = "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";

$data_string = json_encode([
    'title'    => 'your post title',
    'content'  =>  <<<HEREDOC
      
    Add your post content here

HEREDOC
,
    'status'   => 'publish',
]);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rest_api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password),
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if ($result) {
   echo 'yes';
} else {
  echo 'no';
    // ...
}
```